# перегрузка operator()(int,int) и наследование

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Operator
{
  public:
    virtual int operator()(int, int) = 0;
};

class Sum : public Operator
{
  public:
    int operator()(int i, int j)
    {
        return i + j;
    }
};

class Decorator : public Operator
{
  protected:
    Sum mS;
  public:
    virtual int operator()(int i, int j)
    {
        return mS(i, j);
    }
};

class DecoratorWithLast : public Decorator
{
    int mLastRes;

  public:
    int operator()(int i, int j)
    {
        mLastRes = Decorator::operator()(i, j);
        return mLastRes;
    }

    int lastResult()
    {
        return mLastRes;
    }
};

class Decorator3 : public Decorator
{
  public:
    int operator()(int i, int j, int k)
    {
        return Decorator::operator()(i, Decorator::operator()(j, k));
    }

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    DecoratorWithLast d;
    cout << d(10, 10) << endl;
    cout << d.lastResult() << endl;
    Decorator3 d3;
    cout << d3(10, 40) <<
         endl;  // Компилятор ругается тут D:\Develop\test\Decorator\main.cpp:58: ошибка: no match for call to '(Decorator3) (int, int)'
    cout << d3(10, 10, 40) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

На этот код ругается компилятор:

> ошибка: no match for call to '(Decorator3) (int, int)

Answer (score 4):

[Сокрытие имен](https://rsdn.org/forum/cpp/1307541.hot).

Добавьте в `Decorator3`

```
int operator()(int i, int j)
{
    return Decorator::operator()(i,j);
}
```

Или просто туда же строку

```
using Decorator::operator();
```

Без этого компилятор не пытается искать ничего с именем `operator()` в базовом классе - потому что он уже нашел это имя в текущеи классе.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема состоит в том, что когда вы в классе Decorator3 объявили `operator ()`

```
class Decorator3 : public Decorator
{
  public:
    int operator()(int i, int j, int k)
    {
        return Decorator::operator()(i, Decorator::operator()(j, k));
    }

};
```

то он скрывает оператор `operator ()` базового класса. То есть имена, объявленные в производном классе, скрывают такие же имена, объявленные в базовом классе. Поэтому для обращения к скрытым именам базового класса, необходимо указывать их квалифицированные имена.

Используйте `using` объявление в определении класса следующим образом, чтобы "открыть" в производном классе имя оператора `operator ()` базового класса.

```
class Decorator3 : public Decorator
{
  public:
    using Decorator::operator ();

    int operator()(int i, int j, int k)
    {
        return Decorator::operator()(i, Decorator::operator()(j, k));
    }
};
```

using-объявление вносит имя `Decorator::operator ()` в производный класс.

Либо вы могли бы в том предложении, в котором возникает ошибка компилятора, явно указать, оператор какого класса вы вызываете. Например,

```
cout << d3.Decorator::operator ()(10, 40) << endl;
```

Чтобы было более понятно относительно перегрузки функций и скрытия имен, приведу такой демонстрационный пример.

```
#include <iostream>

void f( char c ) { std::cout << "f( " << c << " )" << std::endl; }

void f( int  x ) { std::cout << "f( " << x << " )" << std::endl; }

int main() 
{
    f( 'A' );

    void f( int );

    f( 'A' );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль будет следующим:

```
f( A )
f( 65 )
```

До данного объявления

```
    void f( int );
```

обе функции `f` видимы в `main`. Поэтому имеет место перегрузка функций, и компилятор выбирает наиболее подходящую функцию. В данном случае это функция `void f( char )`, так как аргумент имеет тип `char`.

Однако после вышеуказанного объявления имена `f` в глобальном пространстве скрываются этим объявлением, и компилятор видит только данное объявление. Поэтому при последующем вызове функции `f` вопроса выбора подходящей перегруженной функции не возникает, так как компилятор видит только одно объявление имени `f`.

Аналогичным образом происходит и с классами, так как каждый класс определяет свою область видимости.

Comment: Ну по факту у них объявление разное (разный набор параметров). Здесь разве не работает перегрузка функций?

Comment: @AndrewMaslov Компилятор сначала в  области видимости определения класса ищет имя operator (). Он находит его, и ему соответствует оператор operator () этого производного класса. Имена, объявленные в базовом классе, скрываются совпадающими именами, объявленными в производном классе. Поэтому компилятор просто не видит объявления operator () в базовом классе.

Comment: @AndrewMaslov Чтобы имела место перегрузка, необходимо сначала найти все функции с заданным именем. А лишь затем из этого списка функций выбирается наиболее подходящая по сигнатуре функция.

Comment: @AndrewMaslov Смотрите мой дополненный ответ.

Comment: @AndrewMaslov, перегрузка работает для функций находящихся в одной области видимости(scope). Стандарт явно указывает, что родительский и дочерний классы не составляют единую область видимости.