# Перегрузка операторов при наследовании

Tags: c++, наследование, перегрузка-операторов

Здравствуйте! Объясните пожалуйста, почему так происходит. Я выкладываю код не целиком, а только отдельные его куски, которые, как мне кажется помогут понять суть происходящего.

У меня есть класс динамического массива *DynamicArray*, в котором определена перегрузка оператора *, выполняющего скалярное умножение двух векторов.

```
class DynamicArray
{       
public:
    // конструкторы
    DynamicArray(int n);                            // конструктор по количеству элементов
    DynamicArray(int *newArr, int n);               // конструктор по массиву и количеству элементов
    DynamicArray(const DynamicArray &obj); // конструктор копирования
    ~DynamicArray(); // деструктор

    double operator*(DynamicArray obj2); // перегрузка оператора умножения (скалярное произведение)

    // еще небольшая кучка кода
};
```

Так же у меня есть класс *MyVector*, который наследуется из класса *DynamicArray*.

```
class MyVector : public DynamicArray
{
public:
    // конструкторы
    MyVector(int n) : DynamicArray(n) {} ; // конструктор по количеству элементов
    MyVector(int *newArr, int n) : DynamicArray(newArr, n) {}; // конструктор по массиву и количеству элементов

    // еще небольшая кучка кода
};
```

Если я запускаю программу в таком виде, то всё прекрасно работает и объекты типа *MyVector* прекрасно перемножаются между собой следующим образом:

```
MyVector vec1(3);
MyVector vec2(3);
cout << vec1*vec2;
```

Но для *MyVector* мне надо добавить ещё операцию умножения на число (что я также хочу сделать с помощью перегрузки оператора *).

Но когда я объявляю перегрузку умножения на число внутри класса *MyVector*, то перестает работать скалярное умножение.

```
class MyVector : public DynamicArray
{
public:
    // конструкторы
    MyVector(int n) : DynamicArray(n) {} ; // конструктор по количеству элементов
    MyVector(int *newArr, int n) : DynamicArray(newArr, n) {}; // конструктор по массиву и количеству элементов

    MyVector operator*(double n); // c этой строчкой всё перестает работать

    // еще небольшая кучка кода
};
```

А вот если я заново переопределю скалярное умножение внутри наследуемого *MyVector* и добавл следующую строку, то всё снова начинает работать:

```
MyVector operator*(MyVector obj2); // перегрузка опреатора умножения и всё снова начинает работать
```

Компилятор пишет следующее:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:31:14: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘MyVector’ and ‘MyVector’)
  cout << vec1*vec2;
          ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:7:0:
MyVector.h:38:11: note: candidate: MyVector MyVector::operator*(double)
  MyVector operator*(double n);     // перегрузка опреатора умножения (на число)
           ^~~~~~~~
MyVector.h:38:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘MyVector’ to ‘double’
```

Почему он перестаёт видеть скалярное умножение внутри базового класса *DynamicArray* при добавлении умножения на число?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сокрытие имен.

Надо использовать в производном классе, например,

```
using DynamicArray::operator*;
```

См. вот этот вопрос - [перегрузка operator()(int,int) и наследование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592870/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-operatorint-int-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/592879#592879)

Можете также почитать [вот это](http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/1002058/82/Mayers_-_Effektivnoe_ispolzovanie_CPP.html).

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое. Извиняюсь за повтор, куда глаза глядели - не знаю :(